# How can I toggle the Git Commit Input in the Source Control View in VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

At the top of the Source Control View in VS Code, there's an input box for entering a commit message. How can I toggle the visibility of this input box? Is there a setting to do this? If so, what is that setting called?

Comment: meta note: I wrote this to add a Q&A pair into the SO knowledge base for this reddit question: https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/15ngv5k/unable_to_write_git_message/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `git.showCommitInput` setting.