# How can I make VS Code's Source Control View only show changed files and nothing else?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-git

In the Git tab in VS Code, there are a number of features I never use, I prefer typing my command lines.
Is there a way to only view changed files in different repos of the workspace?

It is very hard to read and navigate between repos with the big commit button, commit input, and short cut commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can get is something like the following in [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson) (some lines commented out and left to taste):

```json
// "scm.showChangesSummary": false,
// "scm.showIncomingChanges": "never",
// "scm.showOutgoingChanges": "never",
"git.showCommitInput": false,
"scm.showInputActionButton": false,
"scm.showActionButton": false,
// "git.showActionButton": {
//     "commit": false,
//     "publish": false,
//     "sync": false,
// },
"git.showInlineOpenFileAction": false,
```

---

> I prefer typing my command lines

Frame challenge: If you prefer to use the commandline, why not just run `git status` and just never look at VS Code's SCM View?

---

Related: [How can I toggle the Git Commit Input in the Source Control View in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76878803/11107541)

Comment: I use the git tab to view files that changed and compare them to previous version to check if I didn't leave unwanted code before I commit. git status offers a poor experience. Also, because I use Firebase functions, I need to know which ones I need to update, as some files are used by many functions using it.. So I need vscode UI to quickly show references from a changed file... Anyway, Thank you for your answer. My git tab looks much nicer now